# Determine if regression results are significantly better with method A or method B

Tags: regression, statistical-significance

I'm working on a regression case and I am using two methods, lets say method A and B.

Due to the randomness in the optimisation techniques of these methods the output will always differ slightly. Lets say I use a metric such as the mean absolute error (MAE) to determine how much the predicted values differs form the actual values. How do I determine if method A is significantly better than method B ?

A practical example.

Method A gives on 10 runs these MAE scores

```
0.55
0.54
0.50
0.52
0.56
0.56
0.55
0.57
0.58
0.57
0.59
```

Method B gives on 10 runs these MAE scores

```
0.30
0.29
0.31
0.30
0.29
0.31
0.28
0.32
0.30
0.31
```

I would appreciate this example worked out. I think the student t-test of F-test should be used here .. but I am unsure.

Comment: What do you mean by "10 runs"? Are there 10 distinct data sets?

Comment: No 1 dataset. The two regression methods are each executed 10 times on the data, on these results the MAE score is calculated.

Comment: Since it is only one dataset, you cannot conclude anything about whether one method is better than the other in general: you can only conclude that B is better than A on this particular dataset (which is obvious from the results you posted--no statistical test is needed).